# differential equation looks like Bessel but isn't

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have this question
[image]

What I did is:
$U=X(x)*T(t)$
after putting it back into the function I got
$-x^2*T''/T= x^2X''-2xX'+2X $
after deviding by  $x^2$ remembering to check $x=0$ I get

$-T''/T= X''-2/x*X'+2/x^2*X=-lamda $
now take the X part

$X''-2/x*X'+2/x^2*X=-lamda$

$x^2X''-2xX'+(2+x^2lamda)*X=0$

so this looks almost like Bessel function just the coefficient of X' is (-) and not (+).
is their a way to change it to Bessel function?

- it sounded we shouldn't use series solution but bring it to a known function

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to change to Bessel DE/functions? If you give Wolfram Alpha the input
`Solve x^2 *y'' - 2*x* y'+(2+x^2*a)*y=0` you get (with your notation)
$$X(x) = c_1 x e ^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}x} + c_2 x e ^{+\sqrt{-\lambda}x}.$$
So depending on the sign of $\lambda$ you should have solutions with $\exp$ or $\sin / \cos.$

Comment: does it mean that it is a regular euler function?
I thought it should be transformed to a Bessel function because it looks almost like a bessel function

Comment: a regular euler function is x^2y''+xy'+ay=0

Comment: It's not Euler's Equation because of the third term.

Comment: Any hint how I should solve it? Should it be done by series solution?